# Sherlock ActionBar and Sliding menu not worked

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

In my application i  want to use sliding menu and the Action bar which i should use is Sherlock Action bar im use this library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu and this  http://actionbarsherlock.com/ but when Add ActionBarSherlock as a dependency to SlidingMenu 
my project give me error: Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: Does your project libs folder contains android-support-v4?

Answer (score 0):

As SlidingMenu Library Contains android-support-v4 which also presents in your project libs folder. Try to delete that from your library project. And then clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Your ProjectFolder>>Lib Folder>> android-support-v4.jar**

Your projects android-support-v4.jar this lib paste in Lib folder of slidingmenulibrary and ActionBarSherlock .
and Then Clean Your project

may it helps You

Answer (score 0):

im solved it,iam used appcompat-v7 and actionbarsherlock im remove appcompat-v7 libsolved problam